# How to deploy C# DLL of hidden NuGet dependency automatically when mixing .Net Standard and .Net Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I have a Visual Studio (2017) C# solution which is structured like this:

- Solution

  - ExeProject
  - DLLProject

    - NuGet-Dependency to `Stateless` package ("Stateless" is the name of the package)

The DLLProject hides the dependency within its interfaces, i.e. the usage of the `Stateless` library is supposed to be an implementation detail of `DLLProject`.

The `ExeProject` accesses only the public interfaces and factories of `DLLProject`.

Due to reasons which go beyond the scope of this question, `ExeProject` targets `.Net Framework 4.6.1`, while `DLLProject` targets `.Net Standard 2.0`.

This compiles fine, but when debugging, the `Stateless.dll` is not found by the executable.

Is it possible to automatically deploy that DLL when linking against `DLLProject` without adding a `Stateless` NuGet dependency to the `ExeProject`?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid adding a nuget dependency?  This is exactly what they are designed for.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Maintainability, Compatibility, Testability, Interface Segregation etc. I want to be able to alter/switch out/remove the library in question without having to modify the `ExeProject`. It's not that important in the minimal example I provided, but the real task at hand has multiple of these issues.

Comment: Can you make DLLProject .Net Framework 4.6.1? Should "just work" if its all in the same solution.

Comment: @mxmissile `DLLProject` is additionally used in environments where .Net Framework is not available, so unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET Core this transitive NuGet dependencies work automatically.

On .NET Framework, there is a "Copy Local" option for referenced libraries. Make sure that it is set to True for the problematic one.

**Update**

For your case, .NET Framework App and .NET Standard lib, the setup requires manual modification of the .NET Framework app's .csproj file. Please follow:
[Copy all dependencies from .Net Standard libraries to .Net Framework Console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51155274/copy-all-dependencies-from-net-standard-libraries-to-net-framework-console-app)

Comment: My Exe project targets.NET Framework (it targets Desktops specifically) while the DLL targets .Net Standard. I updated the question to include that detail. Any chance to get it to work automatically in that case?

Comment: Updated the answer.