# VBA Function: Call Com Class works, Nuget-Package-Function not

Tags: c#, vba, nuget, .net-standard

i've got a .net Standard 2.0 dll with a com Interface which i am calling from VBA:

```
Set xExample = New Example.Example_COM

Response = MsgBox(xExample.Function01("A"))
```

It works, everything is fine. But now i am Adding my own nuget Package(net standard) into Example DLL and calling a function from this Nuget Package. But now i get an Error in VBA:

> Could not load file or assembly "Logging, Version 0.0.0.0"......

First: I dont know why it doesn't have the proper Version number
Second: the Logging.dll should be via nuget in the Example.DLL. It crashes as soon as I am calling something from the Logging Nuget....

Everything is signed and has strong names... Somebody has an Idea?

Update: The Example Config

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <Company>OwnCompany</Company>
    <Description>OwnCompany.Example - Description</Description>
    <Copyright>Copyright © 2020</Copyright>
    <PackageId>OwnCompany.Example</PackageId>
    <RootNamespace>OwnCompany.Example</RootNamespace>
    <Version>2.0.100</Version>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>Example.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="OwnCompany.Logging" Version="2.2.109" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51155274/copy-all-dependencies-from-net-standard-libraries-to-net-framework-console-app

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the input. Used it in the Example Class. sadly didn't help. Maybe to clarify: i have an Excel Sheet with VBA open to call the comClass which also calls a Method from a NugetPackage and then i get the error.

Comment: Next problem you'll have is that the runtime looks in the wrong place for the dependent assembly.  It looks in the GAC first, the directory that contains the .exe (the Office directory) next.  *Not* in the directory that contains the main assembly that you registered.  The usual workarounds get difficult with a .netstandard assembly, AppDomain.AssemblyResolve is about all you got.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Logging assembly is not being loaded properly in the VBA environment. Here are some things you could try:

Make sure the Logging assembly is included in the same directory as the Example assembly, or in the system path.
Try specifying the assembly version number in the PackageReference section of the Example project file.
Try signing the Logging assembly with the same key file as the Example assembly.
Try manually registering the Logging assembly for COM interop using regasm.
If none of these solutions work, you could try using a tool like Dependency Walker to identify any missing dependencies in the Logging assembly, or enabling Fusion logging to get more detailed information about the assembly loading process.