Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Graph, Version=5.50.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies
I have a net472 app referencing a netstandard2.0 project. That project (the netstandard2.0 project) has Microsoft.Graph version 5.50.0.0 installed. The package shows up with no errors or warnings in the solution explorer:

When I call the code from the netstandard2.0 assembly, I get the following error:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Graph, Version=5.50.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Graph, Version=5.50.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at Shelby.Infrastructure.Communication.Services.MsGraphEmailService.d__7.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Shelby.Infrastructure.Communication.Services.MsGraphEmailService.SendAsync(EmailMessage emailMessage, Nullable`1 futureSendDateTime)
   at Shelby.Web.Test.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\jpayer\Development\repos\SS-Financials\Shelby.Web.Financials\Test.aspx.cs:line 45
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Shelby.Web.UI.ShelbyPage.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\jpayer\Development\repos\SS-Financials\Shelby.Web.UI\ShelbyPage.cs:line 106
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Shelby.Core.Domains.Helpers.AsyncHelper.RunSync[TResult](Func`1 func)
   at Shelby.Web.UI.ShelbyPage.InvokeSync[T](Func`1 factory) in C:\Users\jpayer\Development\repos\SS-Financials\Shelby.Web.UI\ShelbyPage.cs:line 106
   at Shelby.Web.Test.btnSend_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\jpayer\Development\repos\SS-Financials\Shelby.Web.Financials\Test.aspx.cs:line 45

The class library is single-target to netstandard2.0.
So here's the dependency chain: ASP.NET WebForms Framework 4.7.2 (main app) -> .NET Standard 2.0 Class Library.
I'm not sure what to make of this issue.
EDIT 1: Tried the answer from the recommendation from this post. It did not resolve my problem. I got a new exception and it caused the application to perform infinite redirects and crash.
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
    at Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule.Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51155274/copy-all-dependencies-from-net-standard-libraries-to-net-framework-console-app

@HansPassant the answer in that post did not work for me. It gave me another exception and caused the app to go into an infinite redirect loop.
